# NoClassFoundError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary/Base64 runtime exception

Tags: java, apache, classpath

I am not sure why this project compiles but then throws this runtime error.

```
E:\Java Projects\KServer>java Server 8096
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
        at CryptoUtil.encrypt(CryptoUtil.java:60)
        at KClient.send(KClient.java:124)
        at KClient.verify(KClient.java:176)
        at KClient.openConn(KClient.java:115)
        at Server.main(Server.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

Online it says I need to add the codec jar to my class path, but I thought I did.  I have it within the project directory and I compile with

`javac -cp .;commons-codec-1.10.jar`

so I thought it was indeed added to my class path.

## EDIT

Compilation command line:

`javac -cp .;commons-codec-1.10.jar Server.java KServer.java AuthProtocol.java Connection.java CryptoUtil.java KClient.java KeyGen.java UDPResponder.java`

Run

`java Server 8096`

```
 Directory of E:\Java Projects\KServer

03/13/2016  06:17 PM    <DIR>          .
03/13/2016  06:17 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/13/2016  06:55 PM             1,518 AuthProtocol.class
03/02/2016  11:39 PM               956 AuthProtocol.java
03/13/2016  06:17 PM           284,184 commons-codec-1.10.jar
03/13/2016  06:55 PM             2,593 Connection.class
03/08/2016  12:25 AM             2,192 Connection.java
03/13/2016  06:55 PM             2,184 CryptoUtil.class
03/13/2016  06:43 PM             3,706 CryptoUtil.java
03/13/2016  06:55 PM             4,460 KClient.class
03/08/2016  12:25 AM             3,908 KClient.java
03/13/2016  06:55 PM               492 KeyGen.class
03/02/2016  11:12 PM               236 KeyGen.java
03/13/2016  06:55 PM               700 KServer.class
03/01/2016  09:33 PM               573 KServer.java
03/13/2016  06:55 PM               980 Server.class
03/08/2016  12:03 AM               628 Server.java
03/13/2016  06:55 PM             1,257 UDPResponder.class
03/07/2016  08:52 PM             1,007 UDPResponder.java
```

## CrpytoUtil.java

I used an SO answer here where this guy Vikram posted a solution using sun systems' base64 encoding API.  I am trying to get it to work with apache.commons

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

/*** Encryption and Decryption of String data; PBE(Password Based Encryption and Decryption)
* @author Vikram
* Modified by Me suckas.  
*/
public class CryptoUtil 
{
    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;
    // 8-byte Salt
    byte[] salt = {
        (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
        (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
    };
    // Iteration count
    int iterationCount = 19;
    public CryptoUtil(byte[] nacl) { 
        salt = nacl;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param secretKey Key used to encrypt data
     * @param plainText Text input to be encrypted
     * @return Returns encrypted text
     * 
     */
    public String encrypt(String secretKey, String plainText) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException{
        //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        //Enc process
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);      
        String charSet="UTF-8";       
        byte[] in = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
        byte[] out = ecipher.doFinal(in);
        String encStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(out);

        return encStr;
    }
     /**     
     * @param secretKey Key used to decrypt data
     * @param encryptedText encrypted text input to decrypt
     * @return Returns plain text after decryption
     */
    public String decrypt(String secretKey, String encryptedText)
     throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException, 
            IOException{
         //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        //Decryption process; same key will be used for decr
        dcipher=Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,paramSpec);
        byte[] enc = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(enc);
        String charSet="UTF-8";     
        String plainStr = new String(utf8, charSet);
        return plainStr;
    }    
}
```

Comment: "I have it within the project directory" ... in the same directory from which you're running `java`?

Comment: @Andrew regan Uh.  It's in my directory of the .Java and .class files and the directory of which cmd is on but not in the same directory as cmd.exe

Comment: This is quite confusing. Could you post your `java` line alongside your javac one, and also post some code so that we can try to recreate.

Comment: @AndrewRegan If you need any more of the .java file contents, I will be happy to post, but don't want to flood with info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try : Note the -cp works on both the javac and java commands.

```
java -cp .;commons-codec-1.10.jar Server 8096
```

Comment: gawd, I'm such a noob